# Google App Script not updating after saving changes and publishing

Tags: google-apps-script

I came across a weird issue, I created a sample google app script and then published it as a web application. The URL that was published was of -XXXXX format, while I made some changes to the script and re-deployed it as a web app, it did show me the current deployed web app URl, while the 'latest code' showed a URL of YYYYY format. While I do understand that URL-YYYY is my updated google app script, I fail to understand if this is a bug? Or if this is expected (Am I missing something else here)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this issue? I'm going crazy with this, too. I publish and re-publish, and when I try to use my script using the /exec url, it keeps giving me errors of code I deleted HOURS ago. I also think there is a bug when updating changes/urls.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong - sometimes. I have had periods today where my changes are not appearing (content changes to my code do not appear). Restarting chrome, clearing cache do not help. After repeated small tweaks to my code and re-publishing attempts one finally works.
I was using clasp to push, deploy. Attempts to Publish / Deploy as web app from the script editor had the same result.
 It's frustrating not to be able to trust the tools.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "latest code" URL is a *developers-only* address, with a unique ID followed by `/dev`. Only the owner of the script can access this, and it will *always* show the results of the current code.

The published application has a URL with a different unique ID followed by `/exec`. To show results of updated code, the author must first save a new version, then publish that version.

Comment: "Only the owner of the script can access this" **AND** any editor who has **edit rights** on the script too. This was not the case some time ago (I don't remember when it changed) but is the case now for sure.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that a new version is needed for the new code to be published! This was the culprit of my headache and it was also Erik's headache (commenter on another answer)

Answer (score 4):

That is not the problem. There appears to be a bug which does not update the published script.  I needed to delete the script completely, save it and add back my saved code. I kept publishing, getting the "exec" version and it never used the new code until I did this.

Comment: I had the same problem. Did not update the code running under exec after re-publishing. It worked for me when once I published the update as new version.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken how do you "update as new version"? I am making changes to the script but they don't reflect in the spreadsheet. Seems like the spreadsheet is executing a legacy script.